# floating points precision in complicated calculations

Tags: python, floating-point, ieee-754, floating-point-precision

For calculating Catalan Numbers, I wrote two codes. One (def "Catalan") works recursively and returns the right Catalan Numbers.

```
dicatalan = {} 
def catalan(n):
if n == 0:
    return 1
else: 
    res = 0
    if n not in dicatalan:
        for i in range(n):
            res += catalan(i) * catalan(n - i - 1)
        dicatalan[n] = res
return dicatalan[n]
```

the other (def "catalanFormula") applies the implicit formula, but doesn't calculate accurately starting from n=30. the problem derives from floating points - for k=9 the program returns "6835971.999999999" instead of "6835972" and from this moment on accumulates mistakes till the final wrong answer.

(print line is for checking)

```
def catalanFormula(n):
result = 1
for k in range(2, n + 1):
    result *= ((n + k) / k)
    print (result)
return int(result)
```

I tried rounding and failed, tried Decimal import and still got nothing right.

I need the "catalanFormula" work perfectly as "catalan";
Any Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you use this alternative Catalan formula: `(2*n)! / ((n+1)! * n!)`? It ought to be more accurate because the terms can all be computed with integer arithmetic there only be one final division that involved floating point.

Comment: I have to use the denoted formula...that's the problem

Comment: You can get away without using floats at all for this:  at the beginning or end of every iteration through the for loop, `(n+1) * result` is always an integer.  So you can work with integers throughout by: (1) initializing `result` to `n + 1` instead of `1`, (2) replacing the update line with `result = result * (n + k) // k`, and (3) returning `result // (n + 1)` instead of `result`.

Answer (score 0):

See the [bigfloat](http://packages.python.org/bigfloat/) package.

```
from bigfloat import *

setcontext(quadruple_precision)
def catalanFormula(n):
    result = BigFloat(1)
    for k in range(2, n + 1):
        result *= ((BigFloat(n) + BigFloat(k)) / BigFloat(k))
    return result

catalanFormula(30)
```

Output:

```
BigFloat.exact('3814986502092304.00000000000000000043', precision=113)
```

Comment: I get an Error: ImportError: No module named bigfloat

Answer (score 0):

Try calculating the numerator and denominator separately and dividing them at the end.  If you do this, you should be able to make it a little bit farther with floating-point.

I'm sure Python has a package for rational numbers.  Using rationals is an even better idea.

Comment: Dear tmyklebu!

 I Used Fraction package, and that solved the problem.

thank you all!!!

Oren